# Telerik winforms theme color customization

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am using Telerik Winforms in my application. I am looking for the closest theme color combination that matches the client branding requirements.

**I have chosen "Office2010Silver" but I need to change the orange color into red for the entire application.**

It is painful to edit the children elements and the primitives for each and every different control. I am wondering if I can use color blending or any other feature to write some code to change the color of the entire application theme.

Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would post this question to the Telerik forum here: [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/winforms).  You might have better luck with this type of question there since you are attempting to change their own native theme.

Answer (score 0):

Color blending is available as of the Q2 2015 release. Here is more information about it: [link](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/another-tremendous-telerik-ui-for-winforms-release-in-q2)

Comment: The Color Blending option provided is indeed excellent, but it requires us to rebuild the theme and deploy the same. Is there an option to set it pragmatically so as to give end user the flexibility to choose color blend as per her choice?

Comment: Afaik, the functionality is not intended to be used via API. However, if you have the source code you can have a look at the BlendColorCommand class, where all the magic happens.